# Is there any method of converting the data in double?

Tags: c++

There is no error expect the convertion of a data to double. i am not able to convert the draw_hud in double. whenever i am running the program, it is showing the error that cannot convert draw_hud data to double. Can you help me solve the problem. "void draw_hud(double proportion, const player_data &player, const planet_data &planet);" This is the code that i put in player.h file

```
#include "splashkit.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "planet.h"


/**
 * Load the game images, sounds, etc.
 */
void load_resources()
{
    load_resource_bundle("game_bundle", "lost_in_space.txt");
}

/**
 * Entry point.
 * 
 * Manages the initialisation of data, the event loop, and quitting.
 */
int main()
{
    open_window("Lost In Space", 800, 800);
    load_resources();

    player_data player;
    player = new_player();

    planet_data planet;
    planet = new_planet(200, 300);

    while ( not quit_requested() )
    {
        // Handle input to adjust player movement
        process_events();
        handle_input(player);

        // Perform movement and update the camera
        update_player(player);
        update_planet(planet);

        // Redraw everything
        clear_screen(COLOR_BLACK);

        draw_hud(planet, player);// ERROR IN THIS LINE

        // as well as the player who can move
        draw_planet(planet);
        draw_player(player);

        refresh_screen(60);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

// player.h file is starting from here

```
#ifndef LOST_IN_SPACE_PLAYER
#define LOST_IN_SPACE_PLAYER

#include "splashkit.h"
#include "planet.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define PLAYER_SPEED 1.5
#define PLAYER_ROTATE_SPEED 3
#define SCREEN_BORDER 100

/**
 * Different options for the kind of ship.
 * Adjusts the image used.
 */
enum ship_kind
{
    AQUARII,
    GLIESE,
    PEGASI
};

/**
 * The player data keeps track of all of the information related to the player.
 * 
 * @field   player_sprite   The player's sprite - used to track position and movement
 * @field   score           The current score for the player
 * @field   kind            Current kind of player ship
 */
struct player_data
{
    sprite      player_sprite; //Character element
    int         score = 0;
    ship_kind   kind;
};

/**
 * Creates a new player in the centre of the screen with the default ship.
 * 
 * @returns     The new player data
 */
player_data new_player();

/**
 * Draws the player to the screen. 
 * 
 * @param player_to_draw    The player to draw to the screen
 */
void draw_player(const player_data &player_to_draw);

/**
 * Actions a step update of the player - moving them and adjusting the camera.
 * 
 * @param player_to_update      The player being updated
 */
void update_player(player_data &player_to_update);

/**
 * Read user input and update the player based on this interaction.
 * 
 * @param player    The player to update
 */
void handle_input(player_data &player);

//draw the location, score and the process bar
void draw_hud(double proportion, const player_data &player, const planet_data &planet); // ERROR DUE TO THIS LINE

#endif
```

Comment: The function you are talking about in the post description doesn't exist within the code. And the usage of it within the code takes different parameters. Check if you forgot to copy all functions within the file.

Comment: Do you want to convert the planet type into double? The compiler is not able to do thay, because only you know what s a double representation of your planet type. You can either write a function which accept planet and return double or define casting operator for your planet type

Comment: @E.Shcherbo can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Please quote the error message you want to discuss in full, verbatim, directly here, as text. Also please identify the line in the shown code where you get the error message (line numbers are not helpful). You can use a comment, like `/* error message in this line*/`.

Comment: @Yunnosch please check now

Comment: Might be just me, but I have trouble identifying the ful verbatim quote of error message in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your `draw_hud` function to take **three** parameters, namely `proportion`, `player` and `planet`.

```
void draw_hud(double proportion, const player_data &player, const planet_data &planet);
```

but when you call the function you only give **two** parameters

```
draw_hud(player, planet);
```

The proportion parameter is missing.

The answer is **not** to convert a player to a double. The answer is to call your function with the correct number of parameters. Either add a parameter to where you call the function e.g.

```
draw_hud(1.0, player, planet);
```

(obviously I just made up the number `1.0`, only you know what the correct number is).

Or remove the extra parameter from your declaration

```
void draw_hud(const player_data &player, const planet_data &planet);
```

Either way the number of parameters in the declaration and in the function call must be the same.